# To show that either $R$ is a field or $R$ is a finite ring with prime number of elements and $ab = 0$ for all $a,b \in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that $R$ has no nontrivial ideal. Then show that either R is a field or R is a finite ring with prime number of elements and $ab = 0$ for all $a,b \in R$.

I am facing difficulty in proving the above!!

Comment: What are your ideas so far?

Comment: R^2 denotes the set of all finite sums possible and we can see that R^2 is an ideal of R.

Comment: Are these necessarily rings with identity?  I suppose they can't be given the second possibility.

Comment: Indeed, it is possible to prove that a finite, simple ring with nonzero multiplication has identity.

Answer (score 6):

(My version, since I have already gone to so much trouble with steps in comments.)

Actually, there is also the possibility that the ring has one element, and this is apparently not incorporated into the statement.  Assume from now on it is not the ring with one element.

The set $R^2=\{ab\mid a,b\in R\}$ is either zero, or it is not. $^\ast$

### Case 1: $R^2= \{0\}$

Every subgroup of $(R,+)$ is an ideal of $R$. By the hypothesis of simplicity on $R$, $(R,+)$ is a simple, Abelian group, which of course from elementary group theory we know to be of prime order.

### Case 2: $R^2\neq \{0\}$

There exists an $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\neq 0$, so that $aR=\{ar\mid r\in R\}$ is an ideal of $R$ that must be all of $R$. Now, the annihilator of $a$ (by which I mean $\{x\in R\mid ax=0\}$) is an ideal of $R$, which by our current assumption is $\{0\}$, so that $a$ is cancellable in $R$.

Furthermore, there exists $b$ such that $ab=a$. We contend that $b$ is the identity of the ring. If $c$ is any other element of $R$, then from $ac=acb$, we conclude that $c=cb$, and so $b$ really is the identity.

Now knowing that $R$ is a simple ring with identity, it is elementary that for nonzero $a$, $aR=R$ implies that there exists $a'$ such that $aa'=1$, and therefore $R$ is a field.

---

$^\ast$ Purposefully not talking about the ideal product of $R$ with itself (which is defined differently.) I really mean the set of pairwise products.

Comment: "and since $R$ is finite ... " how ? In the second case you are considering $R$ is not necessarily finite for example just take $R=\mathbb R$ which satisfies all the hypothesis of the question ... or am I missing something ... ?

Comment: @SouvikDey Yes, the version I had in mind assumed $R$ is finite from the outset, but I will have to do something about accommodating the problem you mention...

Comment: @rscwieb : yes , no problem , please do the needed modification , I am eager to see any answer fundamentally different from the one I gave :)

Comment: @SouvikDey I think I've got it now. Cancelability can be achieved without the finiteness argument.

Comment: @SouvikDey $ann(a)\lhd R$, and since there exists $b\notin ann(a)$, $ann(a)\neq R$, i.e. $ann(a)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @rschweib : that's a good solution ...

Comment: just one typo ; $R^2 \ne \{ ab : a,b \in R \}$

Comment: @SouvikDey It's not a typo, it's the notation I'm using. Actually, there is no need to talk about the ideal product of $R$ with itself, although you could use it.

Comment: @rscwieb : yes I see that it is not needed that the set is an ideal ...

Comment: @rschwieb : I was wondering if the part about the annihilator in your proof is really necessary. You already know that $a R = R$ and so every $c \in R$ is of the form $c = a c'$ for some $c' \in R$. It seems to me that this implies $cb = ac' b = ac' = c$ because $R$ is commutative and hence $b$ is the identity. Am I missing something?

Comment: You *can* use the product ideal; by assumption, either $R^2=\{0\}$ or $R^2=R$. The only problem I see is that the original statement misses the assumption that $R\ne\{0\}$: the trivial ring satisfies the property of having no nontrivial ideal, but it's neither a field nor a zero ring with a prime number of elements. Without this assumption, also your proof fails in the case $R^2=\{0\}$.

Comment: @egreg I'm a bit puzzled by the emphasis on "can". Did someone say can't? yup, the trivial ring edge case is indeed possible, and I have since edited to mention it.

Comment: @rschwieb Anyway, some exterminator who apparently dislikes correct answers has found the thread. I'll upvote your answer (although I don't like it): I think it's really a bad thing that the only incorrect one has positive votes.

Answer (score 6):

Correct statement:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring having only the ideals $\{0\}$ and $R$, then exactly one of the following conditions holds
>
> 1. $R$ is a field
> 2. $R$ is a finite zero ring (that is, for all $a,b\in R$, $ab=0$) with a prime number of elements
> 3. $R$ is the trivial ring $\{0\}$.

The assumption that $R$ is commutative can be removed, if we substitute the assumption on ideals to be “having only the right ideals $\{0\}$ and $R$”. Of course condition 1. becomes “$R$ is a division ring”.

Suppose $R\ne\{0\}$.

Given $a\in R$, we either have $aR=R$ or $aR=\{0\}$. Let $J=\{a\in R:aR=\{0\}\}$. It is easy to prove that $J$ is a right ideal of $R$, so either $J=\{0\}$ or $J=R$.

In the case $J=R$, we have $R^2=\{0\}$; therefore $R$ is a zero ring, so any of its additive subgroups is an ideal; since there are no nontrivial ideals, $R$ must be a simple abelian group, hence finite with a prime number of elements.

We remain with the case $J=\{0\}$. This means that, for every $a\in R$, $a\ne0$, we have $aR=R$.

Given $a\ne0$, we have that $\operatorname{rann}(a)=\{x\in R:ax=0\}$ is either $\{0\}$ or $R$; but since $J=\{0\}$, we can only be in the first case. So every nonzero element is left cancellable: $ax=ay$ and $a\ne0$ implies $x=y$. Fix $z\ne0$; since $zR=R$, there is $e\in R$ with $ze=z$. If $a\in R$, we have $zea=za$ and so $ea=a$, by left cancellation.

Therefore $e$ is a left identity for $R$. For $a\in R$ we have
$$
(ae-a)z=aez-az=az-az=0
$$
so $ae-a=0$. Hence $e$ is also a right identity.

Proving now that $R$ is a division ring is easy.

Comment: The OP certainly has a lot of pitfalls....

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I misread that as the annihilator of $a$. I guess their proximity fooled me (and maybe my mobile device.) Cleaning up my comments.

Comment: If $R^2=\{0\}$ how did you get that $R$ is zero ring? Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: @RFZ A zero ring is a ring in which $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in R$.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks! I thought that zero ring is a ring which consists of zero only.

Comment: let me ask you one more question: you got that $(ae-a)z=0$. How it follows that $ae-a=0$?

Comment: @RFZ Left cancellation: since $(ae-a)z=0$, we have $(ae-a)z=(ae-a)0$; if $ae-a\ne0$ we get $z=0$, contrary to the assumption that $z\ne0$.

Comment: Before your reply I was thinking that this also follow from the fact that $(ae-a)R=\{0\}$ so $ae-a\in J$ but $J=\{0\}$ so $ae=a$, right?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** for any (commutative) ring, we can consider the ideal generated by $a \in R$, we can define simply as
$$
\langle a \rangle = \{ra:r \in R\}
$$
If $\langle a \rangle$ is always trivial, what can you conclude?

---

Suppose that for some element $a \in R$ we have $\langle a \rangle = R$.  Then $a$ is a unit and therefore $\exists 1 \in R$.  Thus, $\forall b \in R$, $b \in \langle b \rangle$.
Thus, $\langle b \rangle = \{0\} \implies b = 0$. Thus, $b \neq 0 \implies \langle b \rangle = R$. Conclude that $R$ is a field.

Suppose otherwise.  The desired conclusion regarding the product is immediate, but it remains to be shown that there is a prime number of elements.  In fact, it's not clear to me that this should be the case.

In fact, here is a counterexample: take $R = \{0,1,2,3\}$ under the product $\forall a,b \in R:ab = 0$.  It seems to me that $R$ is indeed a commutative ring with the desired property.

Comment: But you cannot consider that the ring has unity!

Comment: I think it has to be proved.

Comment: I also agree with you. But then in the answer why is the existence of the unity considered? I think the existence of unity is needed to prove the ring is division ring.

Comment: The statement I apparently claimed without proof is that in any finite ring where $\langle a \rangle=R$, $a$ must be a unit. I don't remember my reasoning.

Comment: But here R is a division ring. R need not be finite. But in the other case R must be finite.

Comment: Now I remember! It suffices to note that the map $x \mapsto ax$ is invertible. Thus, it permutes the elements of the ring. Thus, there is an integer $k$ for which $x\mapsto a^k x$ is simply the identity permutation, which is to say that $a^{k-1}=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Wait, that's not right. Maybe I had misread the question. It's been a year, mind you

Comment: But if the ring is with divisor of zero how is the map injective?

Comment: That's ok. But I post the same question which was closed as duplicate. Can you please reopen the questio?

Comment: Because our supposition was that $\langle a \rangle = R$. The ideal generated is precisely the image under this map. For finite sets, injective is equivalent to surjective. I can't remember if I had considered the infinite case, or missed it from the wording of the question.

Comment: I don't have that authority, but you have my vote.

Comment: Thanks. But the where can I get the correct and complete solution?

Comment: Again, when you are finding the value of the inverse of a you are actually using the fact that a is a unit.

Comment: You keep saying that, but I did no such thing. Good luck, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It is easy to prove that if $aR=R$, then $R$ has identity. Firstly, from $aR=R$, you have that multiplication by $a$ is surjective, hence 1-1, because $R$ is finite. So $a$ is cancellable. Secondly, $ab=a$ for some $b$. We contend that $b$ is the identity of the ring. To that end, if $c$ is another element, from $ca=cab$ we conclude that $c=cb$ from cancellability.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : there are some issues with your answer I think ... first of all $\langle a \rangle $ is usually denoted to be smallest ideal containing $a$ and when $R$ does not have a unity , it need not necessarily be $aR$ , for example take $R=2\mathbb Z ; a=2$ , then $aR=4\mathbb Z$ which does not even contain $a=2$ ... in general you can only say $aR \subseteq \langle a \rangle$ , and in that case $\langle a \rangle =R \implies a$ is a unit proof of yours appears to be invalid . Apart from that , it is clear to me anyhow that $aR$ is indeed an ideal , (continued in the next comment)

Comment: @SouvikDey Good point (about the notation). I think if Om switches to $aR=R$, everything is OK.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : (continued from the previous comment ) then from assumed conditions on the ring $aR=0$ or $R$ but from what you have written I see no way of deciding whether $aR=R$ or not ....

Comment: @SouvikDey If $R^2\neq\{0\}$, then there exists $a$ such that $aR=R$, then there exists an identity. Afterward, $cR=R$ for every nonzero $c$.

Comment: @rschwieb : I think that part of the argument should go like this : suppose $\exists a,b \in R : ab \ne 0$ , then the ideal $aR \ne 0$  ,so $aR=R$ , we are still not done because as of for now we don't know whether $R$ has unity or not , but $R$ indeed has a unity now by the result " If a finite commutative ring has an element which is neither zero nor a zero-divisor then the ring has a unity and any element which is not a zero-divisor ( nor zero) must be a unit " .. this still does not take care of the prime number of elements claim though ...

Comment: @rschwieb : yes exactly ... the ideal  $R^2$ has to be used and from there the prime number of elements would also follow ( with which Om was struggling and even ventured saying that the proposition in that case is not true ... ) ... I think I will write an answer in light of clarifying these confusions ...

Comment: @SouvikDey Ugh, maybe you're right. When I skimmed this initially I thought he had everything except the identity problem solved.  When $R^2=\{0\}$, every subgroup of $(R,+)$ is an ideal of $R$, and the only way you can avoid nontrivial subgroups of a finite group is to have a prime number of elements.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm guessing you took the integers modulo $4$ as the abelian subgroup for your ring. But then $\{0,2\}$ is a nontrivial ideal of the ring you're suggesting.

Comment: @rschwieb : yes , your subgroup argument is correct , that's basically what I have written in my answer ...

Comment: @rschwieb : yeah , mistakes happen , for example I just realized that my quoted result about finite commutative rings is  of "no use in this problem " :p , still it is good to see everybody is struggling and understanding eventually :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, my earlier note about cancelability of $a$ has to have finiteness replaced. I had misread the problem as a problem on finite rings. Most of the comment still works.

Comment: It is a bit misleading when you say that the ideal generated by $a$ is $Ra$.  That is not true in the general case (where $R$ need not be unital), where the ideal generated by $a$ is in fact $\mathbb{Z}a+Ra$.  But since you specifically say that you are talking about $Ra$, then it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be our ring with desired properties . As $R$ is an ideal of $R$ we can consider the ideal $R^2:=R.R$ ( all finite sums of the form $\sum _ia_ib_i , a_i , b_i \in R$ ) . By hypothesis , $R^2= 0$ or $R$ ( by $0$ here I mean the zero ideal ) ; if $R^2=0$ then $ab=0 , \forall a,b \in R$ , then every subgroup of $(R,+)$ is an ideal of $R$ ( why ?) and since $R$ has no non-trivial ideal , so $(R,+)$ has no non-trivial subgroup , so then by a  well-known result in group theory $(R,+)$ is a cyclic group with prime number of elements . Now for the other case , if $R^2 \ne 0$ . If it were the case that $ab= 0 , \forall a,b \in R$ , then $R^2=0$ (because its elements are all finite sums of the form $\sum_i a_i b_i$ ) no ! , so $\exists a,b \in R$ such that $ab \ne 0$ , so then $aR \ne 0$ , but $aR$ is an ideal ( not the ideal generated by $a$ though , still an ideal it is ) so by hypothesis $aR=R$ , so then $\exists e_0 \in R : ae_0=a$ , then consider any $r \in R=aR$ , then $\exists x_r \in R : r=ax_r$ , then $re_0=ax_re_0=x_rae_0=x_ra=ax_r=r$ , so $e_0$ is a ( and "the " ) unity of $R$ , so we have established that $R$ is a commutative ring with more than one element ( as $R^2 \ne 0$) and with unity with only trivial ideals thus $R$ must be a field