# A problem from the book, "Topics in Algebra" by I.N Herstein from Chapter- 3 (Ring Theory) , Section-3.5, Page number- 140 (2nd Edition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring such that the only right ideals of $R$ are $(0)$ and $R.$ Prove that either $R$ is a division ring or that $R$ is a ring with a prime number of elements in which $ab = 0$ for every $a,b\in R.$

This was a problem from the book, "Topics in Algebra" by I.N Herstein from Chapter- 3 (Ring Theory) , Page number- 140 (2nd Edition).

Preceeding this problem there was an excercise as follows:

> Let $R$ be a ring with unit element, $R$ not necessarily commutative, such
> that the only right-ideals of R are $(0)$ and $R.$ Prove that R is a division ring.

I think we should somehow use the above result in that excerise. So, I broke down this problem to two parts: $(i)$ The ring $R$ has a unit element, and then $R$ is indeed a divison ring from the above result.

$(ii)$ The ring $R$ has no unit element. It is this case, I am having the problem with.

I don't know how to proceed with this. I think I might be going in the wrong direction, though. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: pick any nonzero $a$ and the additive group $\mathbb{Z}a$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: @user10354138 But $R$ may not be $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a ring $R$ with no non-trivial right ideals and $aR=0$ has $|R|=p$ prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046319/prove-that-a-ring-r-with-no-non-trivial-right-ideals-and-ar-0-has-r-p-pr) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244742/if-s-is-a-ring-possibly-without-identity-with-no-proper-left-ideals-then-ei and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175259/to-show-that-either-r-is-a-field-or-r-is-a-finite-ring-with-prime-number-of (question refers to commutative rings but answers discuss the noncommutative case)

Comment: @ThomasFinley $\mathbb{Z}a$ or $a\mathbb{Z}$ is the very standard notation for the additive group generated by $a$.  It has nothing to do with multiplication in $R$.